# Imagick, unable to load dynamic library due to no suitable image (wrong architecture)

Tags: imagick

I installed both ImageMagick and Imagick on a mac. It seemed to work fine. However, when I restart my apache server, I get the following error message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/imagick.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/imagick.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
```

I selected the 64-bit kernel for the current startup disk but with no success.
Has anyone experienced the same problem and how did you address the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the following link that solved the issue:

http://unrealexpectations.com/blog/2010/01/mamp-imagick-on-snow-leopard/